# Google Authentication C#

Tags: c#, .net, console, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been doing some research on how to get my C# console application to pull data from the Google Analytics API for quite some time now, and I'm rather confused. I currently had an application to do this, but I it has stopped working since it was using API V2.3 (which has been discontinued). I would like to re-write this application to use API V3.0 and OAuth2.0, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the authentication to work properly from the console app.

So my question is this: What "Scenario" would I use in the case where I have a command line application attempting to do OAuth2.0 (Google has a list of them [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)). My guess is that I need to follow the "Service accounts" scenario, but the only reason I assume this is because I don't believe I can do whole browser redirect thing through a command line interface.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google actually has some client libraries that handle this for you. The [.Net one](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2) even has a command line example :)

Comment: Interesting, I'm surprised that I didn't come across this sooner. I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks Josh!

Comment: I was able to get the authentication piece going, but it's worth noting that it requires user interaction (Clicking the button that allows the application to access user data). My understanding is that that is the difference between 2-legged and 3-legged authentication